Verifying the Identity $-i \log(x + iy) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$
I am trying to verify the following complex identity:
$$ -i \log(x + iy) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) $$
where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.
Steps Taken

Define the complex number $z = x + iy$.
Compute the logarithm of the complex number:
$$ \log(z) = \log|z| + i \arg(z) $$
where $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\arg(z) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.
Multiply the logarithm by $-i$:
$$ -i \log(z) = -i (\log|z| + i \arg(z)) = -i \log|z| - \arg(z) $$
Simplify the expression to:
$$ -i \log(z) = -i \log(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) $$

Thus, the imaginary part of $-i \log(x + iy)$ should match $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.
Does this hold?

It's not true. First, $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ is a real number, and the left side is a complex number. Second, $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ is only in the range $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ You can ensure you are in this range when $x>0.$ So it is true that, if $x>0,$ the real part of the left side is equal to the right side.

If you add the two conditions, $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x>0,$ the equality it is true as written.

You have an error step 3: $(-i)\cdot i=1,$ not $-1.$ Also, $arg(z)\neq \tan^{-1}(y/x)$ unless $x>0.$

Umm, the imaginary part is, as you've written it, $-\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ But what does that have to do with the question as written.

You might want to learn about the two-argument arctangent, $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x).$ It doesn't have the problems of $\tan^{-1}(y/x).$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

In particular, $arg(z)=atan2(y,x)$ for all $z\neq 0,$ and is defined even when $x=0.$

@ThomasAndrews - what you're saying is 100% correct, so instead of splitting them into seven or eight comments, why not make your comments into a post?

Because not being true usually means the person wrote the question wrong, and I was waiting for OP to fix the question. @bjcolby15

@ThomasAndrews Got it.
